# Luis intent to identify attachment

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to create Luis intent which will identify message is attachment and call to corresponding dialog.
I am using node js

i am getting attachment but want to put into dialog

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
var msg = session.message;
    if (msg.attachments.length) {

        // Message with attachment, proceed to download it.
        // Skype & MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
        var attachment = msg.attachments[0];
        var fileDownload = checkRequiresToken(msg)
            ? requestWithToken(attachment.contentUrl)
            : request(attachment.contentUrl);

        fileDownload.then(
            function (response) {

                // Send reply with attachment type & size
                var reply = new builder.Message(session)
                    .text('Attachment of %s type and size of %s bytes received.', attachment.contentType, response.length);
                session.send(reply);

            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Error downloading attachment:', { statusCode: err.statusCode, message: err.response.statusMessage });
            });

    } else {

        // No attachments were sent
        var reply = new builder.Message(session)
            .text('Hi there! This sample is intented to show how can I receive attachments but no attachment was sent to me. Please try again sending a new message with an attachment.');
        session.send(reply);
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're asking here, LUIS analyzes only text, and broadly speaking attachments do not have text included in their Activity. It sounds like you might instead want to create a middleware that can call another dialog based on `session.message.attachments[0]` being truthy.

Comment: You don't need LUIS to accomplish this. Just check if the `session.message.attachments` object contains anything as mentioned by @StevenG.

Comment: Thanks ,so basically any attachment goes to None Dialog

Comment: I noticed one thing, after uploading any attachment, luis is parsing text of attachment name, and calling to dialog which are most close to attachment name .

Comment: I am currently able to upload attachment from slack to bot, data is coming perfectly.
I written code to handle attachment in On Default Dialog .
Noticed unexpected behaviour about attachment, lusi is taking attachment name as text and calling to corresponding dialog.

For Example:
Current Output
Let's say my Attachment name is "hi.png" so it is calling to welcome dialog

Actual output should be:
whenever user upload any attachment ,it should goes into default dialog

Comment: I was able to repro this, I'm talking with the team to see if this is an intended behavior.

Comment: @StevenG. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fix for right now using [`IntentRecognizer.onEnabled()`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentrecognizer.html#onenabled). ([example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/feature-onEnabled/app.js))

For this application, what you would be doing is checking for 
[`session.message.attachments`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.imessage.html#attachments). If it exists, then you don't want any `session.message.text` to be sent to LUIS for recognition.

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer('LUIS-ENDPOINT')
  .onEnabled(function (session, callback) {

    // Check to see if this recognizer should be enabled
    if (session.message.attachments) {
      // Do not send to LUIS
      callback(null, false);
    } else {
      callback(null, true);
    }

});
```